# Find physical memory from physical and virtual page numbers and virtual address

Tags: virtual-memory

I'm having some trouble understanding the direction of a question on the assignment and just need some advice as to how I would calculate the physical memory required in GiB from the following question:

> Consider a computer system in which a physical page number is
>   24
>   bits, a
>   virtual page number is
>   52
>   bits, and a virtual address is 64 bits. What is the maximum
>   amount of physical me
>   mory, in
>   GiB
>   , that this system could have?

What would be the first step to calculating the physical memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A virtual page number being 52 bits and a virtual address being 64 bit, there would be;

```
2 ^ (64 - 52) = 4096 bytes per page.
```

Since the physical and virtual page size are the same, a 24 bit physical page address would then mean that the physical memory is

```
(2 ^ 24) * 4096 bytes = 64GiB.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes a lot more sense now after re-reading everything, thanks for the help!